How to have two window.onscroll functions on the same page
I have two window.onscroll functions, each one works, however when they are both added only the one listed first will work?
<script>
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 80 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 80) {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.padding = "30px 10px";
    document.getElementById("logo").style.fontSize = "25px";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.padding = "80px 10px";
    document.getElementById("logo").style.fontSize = "35px";
  }
}
</script>


<script>
window.onscroll = function() {topofpage()};

function topofpage() {
var winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
var scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;
document.getElementById("topofpagescroll").style.width = scrolled + "%";
}
</script>


Use addEventListener() rather than assigning to on<event>

Don't use .onscroll but create the event handlers using .addEventListener

It shouldn't be the first one that works, it's the second one. It's a normal assignment, so the second assignment simply overwrites the first one.

Thank you, sorry I am new to javascript how would I add this to the script? Sorry
